# I find it hard to describe things about sea(or seas)

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural

I am always have trouble expressing ideas about sea(or seas?)

Like, if I was talking with our friends about whether or not  we could see sea in our hometowns.

I was struggling to express the idea that my hometown is not near the sea so it was really hard for me to see sea.

The problem is that I don't know whether to use **sea** or **seas** because I wasn't referring to a specific sea, I was referring to any seas

Comment: You might be having a hard time because it is usually spoken as "the sea" as in "we could see the sea in our hometown". Most of the time, the sea is usually discussed as the ocean or the individual sea, as in the Indian Sea. If you are looking at the sea, you do not say," I am looking at sea" or "seas"; but you may say" I am looking at the sea". Hope that was clear.

Answer (score 3):

You would say "It isn't near the sea".

If you google "define sea", you find that the main definition of "sea" is

> The expanse of salt water that covers most of the earth's surface and surrounds its land masses

In other words, there is only one sea, under this definition, so it doesn't make sense to pluralize it.

However, there are two alternate definitions of sea. Firstly, we have

> A roughly definable area of the sea

You are using this definition when you say "the Black Sea".

Secondly, we have

> A large lake

You are using this definition when you talk about the "Sea of Galilee", despite the fact that the Sea of Galilee is not really a sea in the usual sense but is actually a lake

But in general, unless there is some reason you are specifying a certain sea or group of seas, you can use the word "sea" to basically mean "all of the oceans and all of the seas".